# GAE Python: Static Files not loading in localhost, but load perfectly fine when app is deployed onto appspot

Tags: python, google-app-engine, static, localhost

I'm experiencing a weird problem, searched for a solution but so far, it appears unique.

My problem is, my static files (css, templates, javascript, etc) do not load when I run the app using localhost in GAE. However, when I deploy the app onto GAE servers (appspot), these static files run perfectly fine!

This even occurs for the default Guestbook app found in the GAE documentation.

I'm using GAE launcher (Python) 1.9.6 on Windows. Python is the 64 bit version, 2.7.7. Already made sure GAE is pointing to the right location for python.

I'm experiencing this problem with every app so far, so I doubt it is a problem with the code. However, here's the code for your reference:

app.yaml

```
application: ipeech
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

guestbook.py

```
import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import jinja2
import webapp2


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)


MAIN_PAGE_FOOTER_TEMPLATE = """\
    <form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <form>Guestbook name:
      <input value="%s" name="guestbook_name">
      <input type="submit" value="switch">
    </form>
    <a href="%s">%s</a>
  </body>
</html>
"""

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'

# We set a parent key on the 'Greetings' to ensure that they are all in the same
# entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be consistent.
# However, the write rate should be limited to ~1/second.

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)

class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Guestbook entry."""
    author = ndb.UserProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greetings_query = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'greetings': greetings,
            'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # We set the same parent key on the 'Greeting' to ensure each Greeting
        # is in the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group
        # will be consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group
        # should be limited to ~1/second.
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()

        query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),
], debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% autoescape true %}
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
</head>
  <body>
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
      {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author.nickname() }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
       An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content }}</blockquote>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/sign?guestbook_name={{ guestbook_name }}" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>

    <hr>

    <form>Guestbook name:
      <input value="{{ guestbook_name }}" name="guestbook_name">
      <input type="submit" value="switch">
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url|safe }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>

  </body>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

index.yaml

indexes:

```
# AUTOGENERATED

# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.

- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

Inside the subfolder "stylesheets", main.css

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I did not see a mistake. But you can use this for testing: 1) You can type in the url of your static dir resource to GET the static files. 2) You can use the chrome debugger to see the request, response and the error.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace:

```
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

with:

```
- url: /(.*\.css)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.css
```

Hope it works for you like it work for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in GAE for Windows, where, when guessing the static file's mimetype, sets the mimetype in the header as a python unicode string, throwing a 500 error in the static file handler.

See the following recent questions:

[Google App Engine: Won't serve static assets with below error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106776/google-app-engine-wont-serve-static-assets-with-below-error/24107830#24107830)

[CSS Files not working on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091187/css-files-not-working-on-localhost/24107737#24107737)

Please report in the GAE bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

If your `static` folder is not in your root directory but inside another folder e.g. `app`(as in my case) you need to include that in your `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /app/static
  static_dir: static
  secure: always
```